# perl : comparing 2 arrays of strings iteratively

Tags: perl

i am basically counting the occurrences of "unique _errors" (**1st array**) in "all_errors" (**2nd_array**) iteratively ,**1st array** consists of strings which are sub strings of **2nd array** ..... whenever the sub-string in **1st array** matches with a string in **2nd array** , count is incremented and total occurrences of sub-string are printed in another file at the  end .
 here's what I did :

```
foreach $x (@uniq_errors) {
    $y = quotemeta "$x";
    foreach (@all_errors) {
        if( $_ =~ m/$y/) {
            $count++;
        }
    }  
    print REPORT "\n\n  $x           OCCURENCES=$count";
    $count = 0;
}
```

ex:

**(uniq_errors) array 1** : qw (error 1  , error 2 , error 3)

**(all_errors ) array 2** : qw (error 1 has occurred at time 123ns in port abc  , error 2 has occurred at time 456ns in port xyz   , error 1 has occurred at time 345ns in port xyz )

*output should be :*

error 1    occurrences=2

error 2    occurrences=1

Is the above code right ??

Comment: You'll have to expand your question quite a lot to include some sample input and an example of how your current output differs from what you expect

Comment: the strings for which it doesnt work look like this :
ANA_QDAC_TSHPM_Mx_Mr_FC_H_E_ins

There are quite a few occurrences of that particular string in @all_errors .... but the $count shows 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`qw()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) to create arrays:

> **qw/STRING/**
>
> Evaluates to a list of the words extracted out of STRING, using
>   embedded whitespace as the word delimiters.

Using [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) you can examine the resulting array:

```
my @uniq_errors = qw (error 1 , error 2 , error 3);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@uniq_errors);
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'error',
      '1',
      ',',
      'error',
      '2',
      ',',
      'error',
      '3'
    ];
```

Enabling `use warnings;` would've also given you a hint:

```
Possible attempt to separate words with commas at ...
```

The solution is to declare your arrays without using `qw`:

```
my @uniq_errors = ('error 1', 'error 2', 'error 3');
```